# WCF Parameter Is Always Null

Tags: xml, wcf, web-services

I recently inherited a WCF webservice (LeadService.svc) which appears to accept SOAP. I am trying, unsuccessfully so far, to push data from an XML file into the service's method TestLead().

The following code triggers the service method, but on the service end the value passed in (lead) is always null. To test it I'm running two instances of Visual Studio, one running the service, the other running the consuming test code. I've been chewing on this for a bit and just can't seem to figure out how to successfully pass values into the service method. Composing POSTs in Fiddler has produced the same results (null value for lead). I should note that modifying the service code itself is not an option in this scenario.

All code is from the service except the first piece below, which is the client code.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

**Client**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.xml"));
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
    client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/ILeadService/TestLead\"");
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    try
    {
        var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:54881/LeadService.svc/", data);
        Response.Write(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);    
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <TestLead xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <firstName>test</firstName>
        </TestLead>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Service**

```
ServiceResponse TestLead(SimpleLead lead) // this is always null
{
    // ...

    return sr;
}
```

**WSDL**

```
<wsdl:definitions name="LeadService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:54881/LeadService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:54881/LeadService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:54881/LeadService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/123Services"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ILeadService_TestLead_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestLead"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ILeadService_TestLead_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestLeadResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ILeadService">
<wsdl:operation name="TestLead">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILeadService/TestLead" message="tns:ILeadService_TestLead_InputMessage"/>
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ILeadService/TestLeadResponse" message="tns:ILeadService_TestLead_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILeadService" type="tns:ILeadService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="TestLead">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ILeadService/TestLead" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="LeadService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ILeadService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ILeadService">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:54881/LeadService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Contracts**

```
namespace 123Services
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILeadService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServiceResponse TestLead(SimpleLead lead);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SimpleLead
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="123Services.LeadService">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="123Services.LeadService" behaviorConfiguration="123Services.LeadServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="123Services.ILeadService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="123Services.LeadServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use soap ui to debug service calls. I do not know the correct setup in fiddler. If you start your service projects in visual studio then all you need is the port. The value should be similar to htttp://localhost:5301/myservice.svc. From there enter the dev url in fiddler or soap ui and enter the payload and call the procedure you are debugging. This should allow you to set breakpoints and debug into your service.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have mismatch in service method parameters: in def. you expect patameter of type TestLead, inethod - SimpleLead.

Parameters names and types should match. In other case, you'll receive null.

This kind of issue can be found usualy by SvcTraceViewer.Exe